Job talk Q&A: handling the room vs. being respectful
I am seeking advice on how to handle questions during a job talk that diverts focus from the main presentation. Specifically, I'm concerned about questions that become lengthy (turning into manifestos) or those that are repeatedly off-topic. Ideally, all questions would be prompt and relevant, or faculty members might step in to help. However, if such diversions occur, I've received conflicting advice on how to handle them:

One approach suggests being assertive and "taking control of the room" by interrupting long monologues, and responding with something like, "This is an important question, and I'd be happy to discuss it further after the talk."
Another approach warns that interrupting questions in this way might be perceived as rude or as an attempt to avoid inconvenient questions, which could be especially detrimental during a job talk.

I acknowledge that there could be significant variation between cultures, institutes, or even departments of the same university, but I wonder if there is a general rule of thumb.
My specific context is U.S. research universities.

Is this a hypothetical or have you experienced this? Any problems with your response?

I have not, but I'm being coached by several mentors who advise me based on their experience to embrace one of these approaches (each of them thinking they did the wrong thing and warning me not to repeat their mistake).

If it helps: in my experience, the audience is much more likely to be thinking "Sigh, Colleague X is doing their thing again" than anything negative about you, no matter how you handle it.

If you do interrupt, add "Unfortunately, I only have a limited time here today, and I think your question deserves more time than I have. But we'll have more time to go into it in detail after I've been hired here." [Give big smile to audience]. Of course, if you do get hired, you're sort of pre-committed to spending time with a possibly boring colleague.

It also matters who’s being long-winded. If it’s a colleague it’s much safer to cut them off politely than if it’s the CEO of the company or a high-ranking executive. In the latter cases you’re probably better off giving them unlimited time to talk.

Unfortunately, it is possible to err too much in either direction, and context matters. My spouse calls these sorts of things "not questions," and it doesn't matter where you are in your career, they can be annoying and tough to deal with.  One thing that may help judging whether 1 or 2 is better is how long they've been going on, and what the body language of other people in the room is. If the body language is really negative, then you may have more freedom to interrupt. Also, as unfortunate as it is, there has to also be some amount of cynical calculation about who is asking the "not question." You may need to give more leeway to a senior department member especially for a job talk. And if you have a regular academic career, you will likely end up making mistakes in both directions over the course of it. The good news is that this sort of mistake in isolation is unlikely to sink a job interview by itself.

I think the "right" response largely depends on personality. If you are not someone who will typically respond with the assertiveness to interrupt someone and take control, but would rather let someone finish and then redirect the discussion (gives you more time to think as well), then I would say: pick option 2, because that will be the colleague they will also get day to day.
If you feel you should interrupt the question poser, then look for an opportunity or gap in their monologue and jump in (you can even do that politely by saying "If I may jump in....".
I would never, as a guest or as an interviewee, err on the side of being too assertive - and definitely not at the first try (maybe if they interrupt you for a second time, in which case the audience will likely thank you for telling them off as it will likely not be the first time they pull a trick like that).
What you are ultimately aiming for is that magic combination of alertness and relaxation where you can read the room and respond exactly with what's needed at the moment - but that is Commanding The Room 2.0.

"If I may jump in..." is a great way to interrupt. I also like jumping in with a clarifying question about something they said, as it's not directly cutting them off but steers it towards a back-and-forth that you have more opportunity to wrap up without seeming rude.
